# Sort by generic relation?

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I have two models Post and Comment. Both can be given a Point through an extra ratings app. The Point has a generic relationship to any object necessary and a value.

Now I've created a list of Post and Comment objects using:

```
result_list = sorted(chain(post_list, comment_list),key=attrgetter('pub_date',))
```

The big question is: How can I sort by assigned Points instead of pub_date?

I'm looking for a Solution that does not modify Post, Comment or Point, because Point is in an extra app and I want all of them to work independent of each other. There is a third app that combines them though, so I can have a new view that does the trick. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The other sides msut have a GenericRelation for that being done. There's not a solution fitting ur requirements of not modifying the class

Comment: Is there any way to modify the Model from outside the app? Something like forcing in a mixin or overriding it like I do with templates? Any way to preserve the independence of the individual apps?

Comment: see contribute_to_class in fields

Answer (score 0):

something along the line of the following should do the trick:

```
result_list = sorted(
    chain(post_list, comment_list),
    key=lambda x: sum(
        [
            point.value for point in Point.objects.filter(
                point_for_id=x.id, 
                point_for_class=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(x)
        ],
        0
    )
 )
```

May I however suggest that you man up and modify the points app, a [`related_query_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation.related_query_name) would make this much simpler.

Comment: I'm not really sure if I understand related_query_name correctly. I think I would have to add it to the comment and post model in order to get the reverse relation right? But that would tie their app to the point app making it unable to work independent right?

Comment: The related query name would apply generically, and not only your app.  It would provide means to count points for anything that had been given points.